# Dragging in UIScrollview increases its subviews count

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios6

I am a beginner in iOS. i have created a `UIScrollview` with 5 images and set its width, height and size change according to orientation. After adding all 5 images the scroll view subview count is 5. But when start dragging the count increases to 7. I don't know where the blank view is added.

---

### CODE

```
-(void)addImageWithName:(NSString*)imageString atPosition:(int)position {

    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imageString];
    imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
    // imageView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    imageView.frame = CGRectMake(position*scrollview.frame.size.width*2, 0, scrollview.frame.size.width *2,scrollview.frame.size.height );
    imageView.tag = 1000 + position +1;

    [scrollview addSubview:imageView];
}

-(void)imageLoad:(NSInteger)startImage
{

    int Index = -1;
    for (UIImageView *subview in scrollview.subviews)
    {

        [subview removeFromSuperview];
    }


    for (int i = startImage; i < startImage+5; i++) {

        Index++;


        fullPath = [dataPath stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/image%d.jpg",i]];


        [self addImageWithName:fullPath atPosition:Index];
        scrollview.contentSize = CGSizeMake(i*scrollview.frame.size.width, 0);

    }

}
```

Comment: where assign startImage..?,set i=0;

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you start scrolling, the scrollbar views are added temporarily as subviews.

Comment: is right. To be sure add `if([subview isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]])`

Comment: +1. You may try to `setShowsVerticalScrollIndicator:NO` if you don't need the scroll indicator.